# PHP Session variable not being set, possibly because subdomain on different server?

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I've got a newly set up dev server of a site I built. The dev server sits at a completely different Box and IP.

The dev site is a complete copy of the live site minus updates to paths and databases. The address is `dev.mysite.com` as opposed to just `mysite.com`.

The live site has a number of subdomains attached to it that change skins based on the subdomain, but nothing else is changed. When I try to log in to the dev site, it won't set the Session variable for the login. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By default, session data doesn't carry across subdomains, so that shouldn't be an issue. Is this login issue only showing on the dev site? Are you sure you're calling `session_start()` before using session data? What error are you getting? Can we see the code?

Comment: Your question is really broad, I tried to answer it, but maybe you can be more specific if you can isolate the problem?

Comment: Well I know it's not conflicting cookies. Tried it in a totally new browser with cleared cookies and same issue. I'm sure I'm calling session_start() as well. As for an error, I'm not getting one. As far as I can tell it's just not setting the variable because when I try to retrieve it, it is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Before testing the live site you should test and ensure that the dev site works. In your question it sounds a bit the other way round. Anyway, I see two options here:

- conflicting cookies
- missing server configuration on the dev site

From your question it's hard to say which of those two applies (even not even something else). You should concentrate to get your dev site to work, ignoring your life site. That means, you access the dev site with a complete different browser from a complete different box (if possible) and from a complete different internet connection (if even possible). That should help you to isolate the problem and more easily find out what is going on. Then get sessions to work on the dev site. After it works, you can start to test your live site.

Comment: I'll look into these. As a note it was a project I came into late. A lot of the site was already built. I just finished it. Then it was launched. Now they want to make some major updates. So instead of working from the live site they copied over the live site to a dev server. It's not my job to make it work and make the updates on the dev site.

Comment: Having a dev server is the right approach (like making a branch in version control), I didn't wanted to question that part and I already smelled what you describe. I can perfectly understand you. Maybe just using a second browser (or clearing cookies, but using a different browser is more handy) will help to tackle this. For testing, setup a simple session test PHP script to see if using session basically works.

Comment: Ok. I set up some test files and sessions in general are working. Guess I need to figure out why the sessions in the copied over files aren't working...

Comment: Ok, that's a base to operate on. Looks like this is related to session configuration. Maybe there is a hard-encoded [`session.save-path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) in the live site's application code? Enable [error logging](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) and scan the error-log. This might be helpful. If you're on windows, install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) which comes with a bash and the most needed commands available (and the bonus that you can put your development under version control).

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for you

— Create a cookie and set it for domain and all subdomain (*)

So you need to insert sessions to database, I suggest you to use Zend Sessions.

Documentation : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html